# bash's command number ( \# ) equivalent in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt, ps1

I'm looking for a character to put in my `zsh`'s `$PROMPT` that would be equivalent to `bash`'s `\#` (*the command number of this command*, according to [this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)). So far I've found only `%h` but this is not what I'm looking for, it's equivalent to `\!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already screened the corresponding man page and didn't find anything suitable, I'll present a alternative method:

1. `setopt PROMPT_SUBST`, so *parameter  expansion,  command  substitution  and arithmetic expansion are performed in prompts.*
2. Increment a varable `cmdcount` (initialized with 1) for each executed command via the `preexec` hook: *Executed just after a command has been read and is about to be executed. (...)*
3. Use `$cmdcount` in your prompt.

---

Copy & Paste code for your `~/.zshrc`:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
[[ $cmdcount -ge 1 ]] || cmdcount=1
preexec() { ((cmdcount++)) }
PS1='$cmdcount '                # notice the single(!) tics
```

And here is how it works (left = `bash` with `\#` in `PROMPT`, right = `zsh` with proposed code):

```
bash$ PS1="\# "                                   |  zsh$ source ./above_code
2 /bin/echo some external command                 |  1 /bin/echo some external command
some external command                             |  some external command
3 cd internal command                             |  2 cd internal command
bash: cd: internal: No such file or directory     |  cd: string not in pwd: internal
4      [no command, just pressed enter]           |  3      [no command, just pressed enter]
4                                                 |  3 
4                                                 |  3
```

---

I do not know about the specific behavior of `\#` in bash, but at first glance both shells behave similar now.

Comment: There's no way to disable the reset if I source `.zshrc` again though?

Comment: @shrx : Good point, I improved my code. Probably you even don't need to set an initial value for `cmdcount`, however, I have a better feeling if doing so `;)`.